# How to make a form simulate a desktop

Tags: c#

Right, this "might" be a tough one, as I do not even know where to start with this.

Ok, I am working on a program, which can load visual studio solutions and display them within a form when debugging.

Actually, the program does a whole lot more, but what it does, is strictly classified, so I can not go into that.
Anyway, whatever it does, does not matter in this case.

Here is the plot:

You create a project in visual studio, but when you debug it, it does so on your desktop.

What I need it to do, is debug it within a form, effectively acting as a desktop with a different resolution.

So if the specific program for example, uses Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 30, as a this.left property, it needs to think that the boundaries of the form it is displayed in, is in fact the Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.

I am having difficulties, trying to find out how to handle this.
Should I perhaps catch this type of code and then covert it, to work within the form?
Is there perhaps another way, to make windows simulate a different PrimaryScreen size, based on the size of the form?

EDIT: Perhaps a little more simplified.
I want the from to act as if it was my windows desktop, so any solution i load into the program, get's debugged and viewed in that form.
Handy for if you need to check how your application will look on a phone or simply in another resolution.

Point is that the program itself is going to be an IDE, but rather an online one, in which a group of people can work together on the same application/file, at the same time.

Comment: What are you calling _desktop_?

Comment: I would give you an answer, but its classified ...     Sorry, I couldn't resist.

Comment: What do you mean by "debug within a form"?  Do you want do have a code editor you can step through in that form?  Or should that form display debug output?  Or do you want to run Visual Studio in a sandbox like on a virtual machine?

Comment: Or are you just trying to debug a program that when in production will be run on a machine that has a different screen resolution than your development machine and you want to simulate that resolution?

Comment: Well cadrell, as you seem to be the only one taking this question seriously and the others probably don't like closed source or don't get it. It has to be an IDE in itself, which is able to load Visual Studio projects, so they can be edited remotely, by a team of people in an online real-time fashion, hope that clears it up a bit :)

Answer (score 3):

People tend to use virtual machines for these kinds of 'challenges'. It's surprising how efficient this method is! :-)

Comment: Might want to read the question again.